# PHP nested array get specific key

Tags: php

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [totalprice] => 671 [total] => 0 [price_per_p] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [totalprice] => 312 [total] => 0 [price_per_p] => 2 ) )
```

Trying to get "totalprice" from each array.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $x_values => $x) {
   echo $x[$i]["totalprice"];
   $i++;
}
```

But this doesn't work at all.

```
$arr = array(
            array(
                "totalprice" => "671",
                "total" => "0",
                "price_per_p" => 2,
            ),
            array(
                "totalprice" => "312",
                "total" => "0",
                "price_per_p" => 2,
            )
        );
```

I'd like to get from array 1 at first "loop" and array 2 at second "loop"

Answer (score 0):

Just remove $i index. No need $i variable.

```
//$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $x_values => $x) {
   echo $x["totalprice"];
   //$i++;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it's echo both at the same time, I'd like it to echo array 0 and then 1 etc